# Python: Lists not wanting to work together

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Area ():
    def __init__(self, pos, desc):
        self.pos = pos
        self.desc = desc

area1 = Area([0,0], "desc")
area2 = Area([0,1], "desc")
area3 = Area([0,2], "desc")
area4 = Area([1,1], "desc")
area5 = Area([2,1], "desc")
area6 = Area([3,1], "desc")
area7 = Area([3,2], "desc")

map_coordinates = [area1.pos, area2.pos, area3.pos, area4.pos, area5.pos, area6.pos, area7.pos]
player_pos = area1.pos

print type(map_coordinates)
print type(map_coordinates[2])
print type(player_pos)

def command(x):
    print "\n" #Just for readability
    global player_pos
    old_pos = player_pos
    if x == "north":
        player_pos[1] += 1
    if player_pos not in map_coordinates:
        player_pos = old_pos
        print "Can't go that way"
    else:
        print "You go north"

while True:
    x = raw_input("type 'north'  ")
    command (x)
    print player_pos
```

What I'm trying to do here is let a person go north if the coordinates are in map_coordinates but stop them if they're out of bounds. However what happens instead is the player can go north forever, and "Can't go that way" is never printed. My guess is that the 'in' keyword isn't playing nice, but all of the types are lists.

Comment: `map_coordinates` is a `list` of `list`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are modifying a list in place, rather than creating a new list with new values based on the old ones.

Neither of the lines `player_pos = area1.pos` or `old_pos = player_pos` creates a new list. Instead, they just create new references to the same 2-element list that was created in your first `Area` call. Each time you modify `player_pos`'s contents, the same changes are visible everwhere else that list is referenced (so `area1.pos`, `map_coordinates[0]`, `player_pos`, and `old_pos` will all see the same changes).

I think you can fix your issue by making both of the lines above copy the list contents instead of just creating a new reference. One easy way to (shallow) copy a list is simply to call `list` on it. Try:

```
player_pos = list(area1.pos)
```

And:

```
old_pos = list(player_pos)
```